# Simplifying $\left\{\left[(2/9)^4\times(3/14)^4\right]^4:(-1/7)^2\right\}\times\left[(-5/6)^3:(5/18)^3\right]^3$

Tags: exponentiation

> $$\left\{\left[\left(\frac29\right)^4\times\left(\frac3{14}\right)^4\right]^4:\left[\left(-\frac17\right)^2\right]\right\}\times\left[\left(-\frac56\right)^3:\left(\frac5{18}\right)^3\right]^3$$

I've been trying to simplify this expression for $3$ hours. I've tried all the properties of the powers I know, and I've tried many calculators online. The result should be $-3$, but the calculators (at least the ones I've tried) and I can not calculate this expression getting the right result.

I understand it's a very simple thing, but I'm losing my mind...

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown uh thanks, sorry this is my first question.

Comment: What does the colon mean here? Division? (i.e., $:$ means $\div$?) Also, what value do you get when you do the calculation yourself?

Comment: @Théophile Yes division, anyway when I calculate this I get the same result obtained by Yves Daoust

Comment: @J.Doe Out of curiosity, could you take a picture of the question and give a link to it?

Comment: @Théophile Sure, https://imgur.com/a/n34sY6B

Comment: @J.Doe Thanks for the screenshot. It seems that you have two typos in the exponents: the first expression in square brackets should be $[\cdots]^2$, not $[\cdots]^4$; and second, you're missing the outer exponent in $\left[\left(-\frac17\right)^2\right]^4$. No wonder you were frustrated! A few minutes of careful proofreading could save you hours of headache later on.

Comment: @Théophile wow, I checked it several times and I did not notice haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the exponents, the global sign is negative.

Proceed by simplifications of the fractions (keeping an eye on the exponents).

$$\left\{\left[\left(\frac29\right)^4\times\left(\frac3{14}\right)^4\right]^4:\left[\left(\frac17\right)^2\right]\right\}\times\left[\left(\frac56\right)^3:\left(\frac5{18}\right)^3\right]^3$$

$$=\left\{\left[\left(\frac13\right)^4\times\left(\frac1{7}\right)^4\right]^4:\left[\left(\frac17\right)^2\right]\right\}\times\left[\left(\frac11\right)^3:\left(\frac1{3}\right)^3\right]^3$$

$$=\left\{\left[\left(\frac13\right)^{16}\times\left(\frac1{7}\right)^{16}\right]:\left[\left(\frac17\right)^2\right]\right\}\times\left[1:\left(\frac1{3}\right)\right]^9$$

$$=\left\{\left[\left(\frac13\right)^{7}\times\left(\frac1{7}\right)^{14}\right]\right\}.$$

Finally,

$$-\frac1{3^77^{14}}=-\frac1{1483273860320763}.$$

Comment: If the answer had to be $-3$, you should question the initial formula.

Comment: this is the initial formula, I get this from a book.

Comment: @J.Doe: sorry, but that's hard to believe.

Comment: it's a first high school book

Comment: @J.Doe: you'd better proofread.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I don't think it's hard to believe at all. Many books have typos. Yes, more often than not, it's a matter of misreading the question, but we can't summarily dismiss the possibility that maybe it's just a bad book.

Comment: @Théophile: I'd rather trust the book than the OP.

Comment: @YvesDaoust That's your choice, of course, and I agree in the sense that it's more likely than not that the book is right. That being said, "hard to believe" is quite an extreme stance. I've seen books where, for example, almost every answer was wrong because the text had been updated to a new edition but not the answer key.